# Fail in querying specific decimal values from AWS Athena with Simba ODBC driver

Tags: sql, r, odbc, amazon-athena, presto

I observe a strange behaviour when querying decimal values from Athena. Identity tests with local values will work for some numbers, and not with others:

### Test 1 with 2.4 -- Works

```r
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select CAST(2.4 AS DECIMAL(10,3)) from test") == 2.4

#    _col0
#    [1,] TRUE
```

### Test 2 with 2.3 -- Fails

```r
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select CAST(2.3 AS DECIMAL(10,3)) from test") == 2.3

#    _col0
#    [1,] FALSE
```

Some more tests with this 2.3 value don't explain anything:

```r
result <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select CAST(2.3 AS DECIMAL(10,3)) from test")
typeof(result)
# "double"
typeof(2.3)
# "double"
paste(result)
# "2.3"
paste(2.3)
# "2.3"
result == 2.3
# FALSE
round(result,3) == round(2.3, 3)
# TRUE
```

Looks like the driver or R would "add" some decimals when retrieving the 2.3 value... but why the heck does it happen for 2.3 and not 2.4 ?
**Note** : I'm suspecting more the driver itselfbecause the issue occurs only on unix, not on Windows.

**Attemps**: I tried to play with the SQL Presto data types (DECIMAL / DOUBLE) without success. Also tried to configure the driver encoding by adding 'DriverManagerEncoding = UTF-16' to `simba.athenaodbc.ini`.

Any help ?

### My connection confiuration:

I'm using a `DBI` connection with [Simba ODBC Driver](https://www.magnitude.com/drivers/athena-odbc-jdbc) (AWS recommendation), with following features :

```r
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                   Driver                = "/opt/simba/athenaodbc/lib/64/libathenaodbc_sb64.so",
                   S3OutputLocation      = "s3://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/",
                   AwsRegion             = "eu-west-1",
                   AuthenticationType    = "IAM Credentials",
                   UID                   = t$AccessKeyId,
                   PWD                   = t$SecretAccessKey,
                   SessionToken          = t$SessionToken,
                   UseResultsetStreaming = FALSE,
                   Workgroup             = 'my-workgroup',
                   Schema                = "my_schema",
                   timeout               = timeout)
```

Comment: Try `select CAST(2.3 AS DECIMAL(10,3)) = cast(2.3 as DECIMAL(10,3))`. Though `select CAST(2.3 AS DECIMAL(10,3)) = 2.3` returns `true` for me in Athena's Presto.

Comment: Yes, returns TRUE as well.